# How can I finish my fragment of TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` and a `HomeTabs` with three tabs (A B C), i set a refresh on `tab C` .

My structure is when i trigger `onRefresh` on tab C , i will switch to `MainActivity`
and load the data again to show the `HomeTabs`.

My problem is when i click back for `finish();` , the layout will show `tab C`.

I try to finish the `Fragment` use like:
    `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();`
or
`((MainActivity)getActivity()).removeFragment(getActivity());`

Both of them are no working , when i click back , i still can't finish the app immediately.

Some one can teach me what step i miss it , that would be appreciated.

My `HomeTabs` extends `Fragment` it use `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` add three tabs

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private Toolbar toolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        // Load the main Fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            switchFragment(HomeTabs.newInstance());
        }
        //take the onRefresh data，send data to HomeTabs and open tab C
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("refresh")) {
            boolean isRefresh = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("refresh");
            if (isRefresh) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putBoolean("refresh", isRefresh);
                HomeTabs homeTabs = new HomeTabs();
                homeTabs.setArguments(bundle);
                switchFragment(homeTabs);
            }
        }
    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    // I try to finsh my tab C , it's no working
    public void removeFragment(Activity activity) {
        activity.onBackPressed();
    }
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            new DialogHandler(this).quickDialog(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.quick),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.confirm),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.cancel),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // If i onRefrsh three times , i will finsh three times... here is my issue.
                            finish();
                        }
                    }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Here is my tab C Fragment refresh call back method:

```
public class MyLineChart extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_line_chart, container, false);

        //.....................

        return view;
    }
       @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            // Both of them are no working.
            //((MainActivity)getActivity()).removeFragment(getActivity());
            //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("refresh", true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Finally my HomeTabs Fragment take the date and show tab C:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        boolean isRefresh = bundle.getBoolean("refresh");
        if (isRefresh) {
            //tab C position is 2
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution to add below code when you are starting activity again on `Refresh` click:-

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

**OR**

Update your MainActivity.java

1) Add function in MainActivity

```
public void refreshFragment() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("refresh", isRefresh);
    HomeTabs homeTabs = new HomeTabs();
    homeTabs.setArguments(bundle);
    switchFragment(homeTabs);
}
```

Now Call that from Fragment Tab C just replacing startActivity(refresh) code:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
mainActivity.refreshFragment();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but when i try your code before my `startActivity(intent);` , there is no working about my refresh.

Comment: Try to  Make replace TAb C again, instead of activity Restart and refresh.

Comment: Thanks again , it much better now , i can finish my app just click back only once , but when i refresh that my tab C layout is disappear , may i know why ?

Comment: Because you are replacing fragment for refresh.

Comment: Mark as answer if your problem definition is solved.

Comment: And Moreover, If you are getting data in OnCreateView using api call, then  you can refresh by just getting data again (call on refresh) and notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: Or whatever process you are doing in onCreateView , just put in function and call that funtion on Refresh click. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a listener in your fragment that can trigger a function in your parent activity
which means you need to add an interface in your fragmentC code

```
public class MyLineChart extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private MyLineChartListener fragmentListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_line_chart, container, false);

        //.....................

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof MyLineChartListener) {
            fragmentListener = (MyLineChartListener) context;
        } else {
            // throw an error
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        // Both of them are no working.
        //((MainActivity)getActivity()).removeFragment(getActivity());
        //getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        fragmentListener.onSettingRefresh();
    }

    public interface MyLineChartListener {
        void onSettingRefresh();
    }
}
```

then you need to implement the listener in the MainActivity code as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyLineChart.MyLineChartListener {

    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private Toolbar toolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        // Load the main Fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            switchFragment(HomeTabs.newInstance());
        }

    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    // I try to finsh my tab C , it's no working
    public void removeFragment(Activity activity) {
        activity.onBackPressed();
    }

    // this function will be called when the fragment is refreshed
    @Override
    public void onSettingRefresh() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("refresh", true);
        HomeTabs homeTabs = new HomeTabs();
        homeTabs.setArguments(bundle);
        switchFragment(homeTabs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            new DialogHandler(this).quickDialog(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.quick),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.confirm),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.cancel),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // If i onRefrsh three times , i will finsh three times... here is my issue.
                            finish();
                        }
                    }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , i try your code step by step , when i refresh that my `finish` problem was be solved , but my tab C layout is disappear ,  about my refresh , i just use the same like `        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            switchFragment(HomeTabs.newInstance());
        }` why my `tab C` disappear ?  May i know why ? Thanks again.